# Pass parameter value from struts2.xml result to jsp

Tags: struts2

I have a program in which business logic return some data. that data needs to show on the jsp. i am able to forward to the jsp based on the result but how can i send the return value.
e.g.

```
public String createuser(String strUser,String strPassword)
{
     String strReturnValue="S0000";
     try
     {
       // My code;
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {

     }
     return strReturnValue+"Token";
}
```

Struts.xml

```
<action name="RegUser" class="....">
   <result name="success">/UIShow.jsp</result>
   <result name="error>/UIError.jsp</result>
</action>
```

in jsp i want to show this token value on success; How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out the [Hello World Struts 2 application](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/hello-world-using-struts-2.html) because it provides a good example of how to do this.

1. In your Action class, you can create a `String` field and appropriate getter method for the token value so that your JSP can retrieve it. In  your `RegUser` action method you will want to assign the field to the result from the business logic, like `tokenValue = createUser(user, password);`
2. In your `UIShow.jsp` you can use a struts 2 tag `s:property` to display the token value, like `<s:property value="tokenValue"/>`

Or, since this is just a `String`, it may be simpler for you to use the [addActionMessage](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/xwork-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/ActionSupport.html#addActionMessage%28java.lang.String%29) method from `ActionSupport` in your Action class (pass in the String result of the business logic into `addActionMessage`) and then use the `s:actionmessage` tag in your JSP to display the token value.